# Aframe state component - template is adding element outside of Aframe

Tags: reactjs, aframe

I'm trying to template an entity using the aframe-state-component:

```
  <a-entity layout="type: circle; radius: 10" bind-for="for: guidePreview; in: guidePreviews; key: id">
          <template>
            <a-entity draw="width:256; height: 256" guidepreview="{{guidePreview}}" bind="data: guidePreview"></a-entity>
          </template>
  </a-entity>
```

I get

> You are attempting to attach  outside of an A-Frame scene.
>   Append this element to `<a-scene>` instead.  aframe-master.js:58249
>   Uncaught TypeError: parentEl.emit is not a function
>
> ```
> at HTMLElement.value (aframe-master.js:58249)
> at HTMLElement.value (aframe-master.js:58112)
> at HTMLElement.wrappedMethod (aframe-master.js:59621)
> at HTMLElement.value (aframe-master.js:58246)
> at HTMLElement.value (aframe-master.js:58112)
> at HTMLElement.wrappedMethod (aframe-master.js:59621)
> at NewComponent.renderItems (aframe-state-component.js:953)
> at NewComponent.<anonymous> (aframe-state-component.js:932)
> ```

This is within scene, however it is also within a React Component (which I need for defining access and routing)

Is the reason the template is getting added outside of scene because of React?

Comment: Does it work outside React? Don't know if that messes things up.

Comment: Can you share a snippet of the `<a-scene>` to show how the component is being used?

Comment: I had a similar issue today, I have a project with Preact and A-frame and I created a Preact component called "StartGameMenu" that I use it inside another component called "MainMenu", the structure of components looks like this: <a-scene> -> Game > MainMenu > StartGameMenu. For some reason the StartGameMenu was rendered outside the <a-scene>, wich does not make sense, since in the structure he is a child of <a-scene>, I tried everything until I change the component name, and finally worked. I dont know why this happened...

Comment: I was wrong in the last comment, I figure out that If I pass setState hook to the component for some reason it renders outside the <a-scene>, I was doing something like that -> `<${InitGameMenu} clickConfig=${setStep("one")} />`, that was fixed with: `<${InitGameMenu} clickConfig=${setStepOne} />`. That was the cause of the problem, not the name of component, but I still dont know why the entity was rendered outside the <a-scene>